# I get an Exception when trying to implement reset password with Authlogic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authlogic, ruby-1.9

I'm using Ruby on Rails 2.3.5 and Ruby 1.9 and implmeneted Authlogic as my authentication engine. Authlogic works fine. But now I have been trying to implement password reset using the following tutorial:
http://www.binarylogic.com/2008/11/16/tutorial-reset-passwords-with-authlogic/

But I'm getting the following exception when I type mysite.com/password_resets/new

```
Processing PasswordResetsController#new (for 127.0.0.1 at 2010-03-13 01:09:45) [GET]
Completed in 9ms (DB: 0) | 200 [http://localhost/password_resets/new]
[2010-03-13 01:09:45] ERROR TypeError: can't convert Array into String
    /Users/tammam56/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p378/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/output_safety.rb:34:in `concat'
    /Users/tammam56/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p378/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/output_safety.rb:34:in `concat_with_safety'
    /Users/tammam56/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p378/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:63:in `block in service'
    /Users/tammam56/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p378/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/response.rb:158:in `each'
    /Users/tammam56/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p378/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/response.rb:158:in `each'
    /Users/tammam56/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p378/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/string_coercion.rb:16:in `send'
    /Users/tammam56/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p378/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/string_coercion.rb:16:in `method_missing'
    /Users/tammam56/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p378/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/reloader.rb:22:in `method_missing'
    /Users/tammam56/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p378/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:62:in `service'
    /Users/tammam56/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.1-p378/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:111:in `service'
    /Users/tammam56/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.1-p378/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:70:in `run'
    /Users/tammam56/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.1-p378/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:183:in `block in start_thread'
```

Honestly I'm not sure where to start debugging for this. Is it because I'm using Ruby 1.9? some people seem to be having trouble with Authlogic and Ruby 1.9:
http://isitruby19.com/authlogic

Please advise me how to go about solving/debugging this issues?

Thanks,

Tam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start by running a test for PasswordResetsController#new action, and post here the output.